# Ansible should only print 'FAILED' after completion of all retries in until loop, not for every iteration

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, ansible-module

I have an Ansible task almost identical to the top answer here: [Ansible playbook wait until all pods running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198576/ansible-playbook-wait-until-all-pods-running)

```yaml
- name: Wait for all control-plane pods become created
  shell: "kubectl get po --namespace=kube-system --selector tier=control-plane --output=jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}'"
  register: control_plane_pods_created
  until: item in control_plane_pods_created.stdout
  retries: 10
  delay: 30
  with_items:
    - etcd
    - kube-apiserver
    - kube-controller-manager
    - kube-scheduler

- name: Wait for control-plane pods become ready
  shell: "kubectl wait --namespace=kube-system --for=condition=Ready pods --selector tier=control-plane --timeout=600s"
  register: control_plane_pods_ready

- debug: var=control_plane_pods_ready.stdout_lines
```

As shown in his example it prints 'FAILED' 3 times:

```json
TASK [Wait for all control-plane pods become created] ******************************
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait all control-plane pods become created (10 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait all control-plane pods become created (9 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait all control-plane pods become created (8 retries left).
changed: [localhost -> localhost] => (item=etcd)
changed: [localhost -> localhost] => (item=kube-apiserver)
changed: [localhost -> localhost] => (item=kube-controller-manager)
changed: [localhost -> localhost] => (item=kube-scheduler)

TASK [Wait for control-plane pods become ready] ********************************
changed: [localhost -> localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "control_plane_pods_ready.stdout_lines": [
        "pod/etcd-localhost.localdomain condition met", 
        "pod/kube-apiserver-localhost.localdomain condition met", 
        "pod/kube-controller-manager-localhost.localdomain condition met", 
        "pod/kube-scheduler-localhost.localdomain condition met"
    ]    
}
```

For my implementation, the loop fails more than 3 times more like 20 times... so it clogs up my logs... but this is expected behaviour.

So how can I only print 'FAILED' once all the retries have been used up?

I hope my question makes sense,
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> *How can I only print 'FAILED - RETRYING' once all the retries have been used up?*

I understand that you are referencing to `until` `retries` and like to [Retrying a task until a condition is met](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met) and the message `FAILED` belongs to the loop and not the final task result.

Running a short fail test

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Show fail test
    shell:
      cmd: exit 1 # to fail
    register: result
    # inner loop
    until: result.rc == 0 # which will never happen
    retries: 3 # times therefore
    delay: 1 # second
    # outer
    loop: [1, 2, 3] # times over 
    failed_when: item == 3 and result.rc != 0 # on last outer loop run only
    no_log: true # for outer loop content
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] **********************************
FAILED - RETRYING: Show fail test (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Show fail test (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Show fail test (1 retries left).

TASK [Show fail test] *****************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=None)
FAILED - RETRYING: Show fail test (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Show fail test (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Show fail test (1 retries left).
changed: [localhost] => (item=None)
FAILED - RETRYING: Show fail test (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Show fail test (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Show fail test (1 retries left).
failed: [localhost] (item=None) => changed=true
  attempts: 3
  censored: 'the output has been hidden due to the fact that ''no_log: true'' was specified for this result'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=true
  censored: 'the output has been hidden due to the fact that ''no_log: true'' was specified for this result'
```

it seems that it is not possible to suppress the interim message of Ansible's `until` `retries` loop on playbook level, neither with [Defining failure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure) nor by [Protecting sensitive data with `no_log`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html#protecting-sensitive-data-with-no-log) or [Limiting loop output](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label).

> *...  but this is expected behaviour.*

Right, unless you are not addressing [Callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/plugins/callback.html) and [Setting a (other) callback plugin for ansible-playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/plugins/callback.html#setting-a-callback-plugin-for-ansible-playbook) or [Developing (own) Callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#developing-callbacks) the message will remain.

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to change the interim message of Ansible's `until` `retries` loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48727195/6771046)

**Further Information**

- [`ansible/plugins/callback/default.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py#L374)

**Possible Solution**

- Ansible Issue #[32584](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/32584)
- [`diy` callback – Customize the output](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/diy_callback.html)

Comment: Ok thats what I expected :/ seems like an oversight. Thanks for the fantastic answer though! Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: @Josh, unless you are not addressing Callback plugins and Setting a (other) callback plugin for ansible-playbook or Developing (own) Callback plugin the message will remain.

Comment: I ended up writing my own logic in a custom shell script, it was just easier for me to do it that way

Comment: @Josh, right, it is also possible to [execute a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73594837/6771046) and transfer it later into an own Ansible module. By doing this the loop logic will be within in the script or module resulting into a changed behavior and expected output.